# Read xlsx file via Powershell - [error] Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

I have a xlsx file in azure blob storage. My target is to read the xlsx file from azure build pipeline and make some changes, then save to the same location. I have tried with this following yml code just to read the xlsx file first

```
 - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
          azureSubscription: $service-connection
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          Inline: |
            $storageAccountName = "resaibdplogbdw21"
            $container_name = "devops-tasks"
            $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount
            $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $context | sort @{Expression = "LastModified";Descending=$true}

            $excelFile = $blobs | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match ".xlsx*"}
            $excelLink = (Get-AzStorageBlob -blob $excelFile.Name -Container $container_name -Context $context).ICloudBlob.uri.AbsoluteUri
            $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
            $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelLink)
```

But it is giving me an error

```
##[error]Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

What I have understood from internet is that - I have to install Cli MS365 first via node in build pipeline. Right now, I am looking for a solution to run the above code. I am not clear what tasks I have to add first to install CLI MS365. Moreover, how would I log in to MS365 by not showing my acutal password.

Comment: The office365-cli does not let you use the excel COM objects/methods. I'm pretty certain there is **no** way to use excel COM from Azure pipelines, since that method relies on the DLLs that get installed with MS Office. You'll want to use the `importExcel` powershell module to manipulate excel files instead

Comment: As Cpt.Whale metioned, office365-cli will not solve this issue, you need to install Office365 64bit. See my answer, there is a method to achieve your requirement directly(Don't need Office365 environment.). :)

Answer (score 0):

As Cpt.whale mentioned, office365-cli will not let you be able to use the excel COM.

A feasible solution is to use a machine to install Office365, and then build a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) based on this machine. After that the pipeline runs on this agent, which allows your pipeline to have the same environment as your local machine.

But the above method means you need to spend time downloading Office and pay for it.

***Here's an implementation based on the python common package (no need to install the Office environment, it can handle xlsx files directly):***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      pip install openpyxl
      
      pip install azure-storage-blob
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      #get file from azure blob storage based on python azure blob storage sdk version 12.13.1
      
      import os
      import sys
      
      from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
      import openpyxl
      
      account_name = "bowmantest"
      account_key = "xxxxxx"   #This is the access key of azure blob storage.
      container_name = "bowmancontainer"
      blob_name = "Book1.xlsx"
      local_file_name = "Book1_1.xlsx"
      
      upload_blob_name = "Book1_1_upload.xlsx"
      
      def get_file_from_blob_storage(account_name, account_key, container_name, blob_name, local_file_name):
          try:
              connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + account_name + ";AccountKey=" + account_key + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
              blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
              container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
              blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
              with open(local_file_name, "wb") as download_file:
                  download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
              print("Downloaded blob to \ " + os.path.abspath(local_file_name))
          except Exception as e:
              print(e)
      
      def upload_file_to_blob_storage(account_name, account_key, container_name, blob_name, local_file_name):
          try:
              connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + account_name + ";AccountKey=" + account_key + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
              blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
              container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
              blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
              with open(local_file_name, "rb") as data:
                  blob_client.upload_blob(data)
              print("Uploaded blob to \ " + os.path.abspath(local_file_name))
          except Exception as e:
              print(e)
      
      def change_xlsx_file(local_file_name):
          try:
              wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(local_file_name)
              sheet = wb['Sheet1']
              print(sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value)
              #change the value of first row first column
              sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = '123'
              #save the file to a new file
              wb.save(local_file_name)
          except Exception as e:
              print(e)
      
      get_file_from_blob_storage(account_name, account_key, container_name, blob_name, local_file_name)
      change_xlsx_file(local_file_name)
      upload_file_to_blob_storage(account_name, account_key, container_name, upload_blob_name, local_file_name)
```

I can do it successfully on my side:

[image]